# If $a,b,c,d>0$ prove $\frac{2a^2+bc}{a+b+c} +\frac{2b^2+cd}{b+c+d}+\frac{2c^2+da}{c+d+a}+\frac{2d^2+ab}{d+a+b} \geq a+b+c+d$

Tags: inequality, substitution, buffalo-way

If $a,b,c,d>0$ prove

$$\frac{2a^2+bc}{a+b+c} +\frac{2b^2+cd}{b+c+d}+\frac{2c^2+da}{c+d+a}+\frac{2d^2+ab}{d+a+b} \geq a+b+c+d$$

I tried cauchy: $$\frac{2a^2+bc}{a+b+c} +\frac{2b^2+cd}{b+c+d}+\frac{2c^2+da}{c+d+a}+\frac{2d^2+ab}{‌​d+a+b}$$ with $$(a+b+c + b+c+d +c+d+a +d+a+b)$$ but I got $$\sqrt{2a^2+bc} + \sqrt{2b^2+cd}+\sqrt{2c^2+da}+\sqrt{2d^2+ab}$$. If without square root, I can get $$(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+d)^2+(d+a)^2$$ and I can apply p-norm.
Thanks

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Moreover, please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Add your working in the body of the question and show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a^2+bc}{a+b+c}\geq\sum_{cyc}a$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a^2+bc}{a+b+c}-a\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)(a-c)}{a+b+c}\geq0.$$
Now, easy to use BW.

Indeed, let $a=\min\{a,b,c,d\}$, $b=a+u$, $c=a+v$ and $d=a+w$ and the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There are many terms. Combine positive and negative terms with shrink and enlarge denominators?

Comment: @Weiqing Wu I proved it by full expanding. I am ready to show. It's very ugly, but it's a proof.

Comment: Instead of BW, could we use a+b+c=u, b+c+d=v, c+d+a=u, d+a+b=t? it becomes $$\sum_{cyc}{u^3*v*w+u*v^2*w^2}\ge\sum_{cyc}{u^2*v^2*w+u^2*v*w^2}$$

Comment: @Weiqing Wu No! After this substitution between $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ can be something negative.

Comment: @Weiqing Wu Try, $u=v=w=1$ and $t=4$. You'll get something bad. It says that $u$, $v$, $w$ and $t$ can not be all positive numbers.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.